# Collation Conflict when patching SSRS

Tags: ssrs, upgrade, ssrs-2014

We recently upgraded our test database servers from SQL 2014 SP2 CU3 to 2014 SP2 CU10. Most of the servers are fine, but on 2 of them we are getting the following error when connecting to the reporting services website:
[image]

sorry, it didn't scale well, the message reads :

> "The version of the report server database is either in a format that
>   is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The
>   expected version is '164'. (rsInvalidReportServerDatabase)"

Having a look at the log files I can see this error:

> library!WindowsService_0!4cc!02/26/2018-12:47:43:: e ERROR: ServiceStartThread: Exception caught while starting service. Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" in the equal to operation.
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

After that we get a number of entries about the database version being incorrect:

> library!DefaultDomain!1bf0!02/26/2018-12:49:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InvalidReportServerDatabaseException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InvalidReportServerDatabaseException: The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The expected version is '164'.;

I'm assuming it's something to do with Collation, but everything I can see is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS. I'm not sure where it's getting the other collation from or how to fix it.

Any ideas on who to get the database to upgrade to the new version?

Comment: Being a Dev server, we fixed the problem by deleting the reporting services database and creating a new one and reloading all settings/reports. Not ideal, but it got us around the problem